# Expo React Native App. After build. When app open the splash white screen and exit problem

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, eas, expo-build

Expo React Native App. After build. When app open the splash white screen and exit problem

1. git clone https://github.com/RaviNakhate/sanatan-bhajan-diary-react-native-app.git
2. npm install (firstly install expo in your system)
3. npm start, check app run
4. after app check, build app
5. using expo build install packages eas and run :- eas build --platform android

Check the issue app is not running

Debug the project when build app. the app is not open.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.